# Slackbot to maintain user state for asking his details

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to build a Slack bot, in which I want bot to ask details from the user, like for example:

Question 1: Please enter your name

Question 2: Please enter your email id

Question 3: Please enter your address

Slackbot is calling an API, for which I added the API URL in Events and Subscriptions so that if a message comes, the API gets called

In the API response along with message, am also returning a field, which am expecting from Slackbot to return back again in next API request(whenever the API is called again for the same user).

Note: The field is required because on the basis of that am maintaining the user state in the backend

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: May be you can use Modals, to capture information in one go, https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals

Comment: @SuyashGaur I checked the docs and found:
The modals returns a field private_metadata, but is returned to the app in view_submission and block_actions events.
I want this in case of event_callback.

Comment: This is just for the Modals, but what I am suggesting is that , for collecting data, can you prepare a modal form and collect it all at once?

Comment: Though that can be done using modals, but my usecase is different, I might introduce some more questions later, so I want to do by maintaining user state

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store the user state in either cache or database.

Using 'Redis' cache is an easy to implement solution.

You can use hash (key-value pair)to store data.
 Store slackID as key and state(can be a JSON object) as value.